# Dynamically render a component in react v15

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an array of `react components` and I am trying to output them:

**this.props.data**

```
           [
                {
                    key: 1,
                    element: 'input',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Jamie is Sex'
                },
                {
                    key: 2,
                    element: 'input',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Jamie is Not Sex'
                }
           ]
```

**input.component.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const input = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
        <input type="text" />
    );
  }
});

export default input;
```

**import components.js**

[image]

**Dynamic Code**

```
import components from '../../componets';
render() {
    return (
        <form action="">
            {this.props.data.map((item, index) => <{components[item.element]} key={index} data={item}/> )}
        </form>
        //{components[item.element]} which would reference 'input' from components.js
    );
}
```

**Output**

```
bundle.js:33283 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../components/Form/Form.component.js"webpackMissingModule @ bundle.js:33283(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:33283__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:32763__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:7464__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:48__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:40(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:43
bundle.js:99 [WDS] Errors while compiling.
```

Comment: hahah i just saw my own placeholder text, I wrote that like 2 hours ago and still it made me laugh. Oh what a terrible life I live :'(

Comment: I believe in this situation you would want to use React.createElement(components[item.element], <props here>) 
for dynamically created components.

Comment: Thing is, `componenets[item.elemet]` reference my react component which was created using `const input = React.createClass({` so I'm not thats right?

Comment: Well you create the Class you did not actually create the element. In your loop when you try to do `<components[item.element]>` is when you actual create the element. I don't think JSX can render a dynamic component like that and hence you need to use React.createElement(); 

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html

Comment: argh yes, ok this makes sense, I will be play with this

Comment: `Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `form`.` so clearly componenets.js isn't actually outputting what I think it is. Playing me I will

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the element via `React.createElement()`, jsx gets transpiled into this syntax, but dynamic elements aren't going to be transpiled.

I'd also recommend you move the mapping out of the return, map it on a variable that you can also check for validity of the data. something kinda like this

```
render() {
    let elems = null;
    let {data} = this.props;
    if(data.length > 0){
        elems = data.map( (item, index) => {
            if(components[item.element]){
                return React.createElement(components[item.element], { key: index, data: item })
            else {
                return null
            }
        });
    }
    return (
        <form action="">
            {elems}
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: Finally got back on the project :) Ok so at least we're getting somewhere: `bundle.js:8493 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `form`.` I will play and make sure all the file names are correct

Comment: Indeed, my file wasn't outputing to the top level so I needed: `components[item.element].default`Cheers for the help. Turns out there was nothing wrong with the code I had written